# .Interior.ColorIndex issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub that copies all cells with text in a column and transposes them on a separate sheet. It changes the fill color of each cell after it is transposed. Then the user can add more data and rerun the macro and it will skip the cells that have already been copied by first looking at there fill color.

Everything works as expected with one exception. Only the copied cells turn yellow after running the macro (expected outcome), but each subsequent cell will change color whenever any data is entered into it (unexpected outcome.) I tried adding a line to change the color of the next empty cell back to 0 but this didn't help.

Is there anyway to keep Excel from reformatting the color of cells after running this macro?

Here is the full Sub

```
Sub TransposeSubLocation()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lYellow As Range
Set sh = Worksheets("Sub Location Lists")
Set sht = Worksheets("Equipment List")
Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

For i = 1 To 1000 Step 1
    If sh.Cells(5, i).Value <> "" Then
        lRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = sht.Cells(5, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        On Error Resume Next
            Set lYellow = sh.Range(sh.Cells(6, i), sh.Cells(lRow, i)).Find(what:="*", after:=sh.Cells(6, i), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchFormat:=True).Offset(1, 0)

        If lCol > 1 Then
            lCol = lCol + 1
        End If

        If sh.Cells(6, i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            sh.Range(lYellow, sh.Cells(lRow, i)).Copy
            sht.Cells(5, lCol).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
            sh.Range(sh.Cells(6, i), sh.Cells(lRow, i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            'Here I attempted to force it back to no fill but this did not help
            sh.Cells(lRow, i).Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

            Else: sh.Range(sh.Cells(6, i), sh.Cells(lRow, i)).Copy
            sht.Cells(5, lCol).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
            sh.Range(sh.Cells(6, i), sh.Cells(lRow, i)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            sh.Cells(lRow, i).Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    End If
Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: What type of error you witness?

Comment: Remove the on error statement and step through your code using F8. Maybe you'll be able to catch the culprit that way.

Comment: There are no errors. The code runs fine. Everything works as expected within the code. But somehow reformatting the cell color with vba causes excel to automatically change the cell color of any other cells when data is entered into them. Almost like a conditional formatting if cell contains anything. If I use vba to change the cell color of A6:A10 to yellow and then manually enter data into A11, A11 will automatically turn yellow after making an entry. This will continue through A12,A13,A14, etc.

Comment: This is not being caused by above code in my opinion. Excel seems to do it by detecting the current region formatting and then tries to continue. In such case, you need to override this manually in cell `A11`. Thenceforth, it shall not affect. I checked in `Excel >> Options >> Proofing` but unfortunately, the options there are limited.